# Find number of permutations $ \delta $ such that $\delta ^4 = \pi$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Permutation $ \pi$ has a signature $2^43^5$ (it contains $4$ cycles of length $2$ and $5$ cycles of length $3$). 
Find number of permutations $ \delta $ such that $\delta ^4 = \pi$

My observation
Cycle of length $3$:
$$\pi = [a,b,c]$$
$$\pi^2 = [a,c,b]$$
$$\pi^3 = [a][b][c]$$
$$\pi^4 = [a,b,c]$$

Moreover for cycle of length $2$:
$$\pi = [a,b]$$
$$\forall_k \, \pi^2 = \dots = \pi^k = [a,b]$$
So it means that number of these permutations is just all possible permutations with given signature?
So it is
$$\binom{23}{2}\binom{21}{2}\binom{19}{2}\binom{17}{2}\binom{15}{3}\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3} \cdot (3-1)!^5 \cdot (2-1)!^4 $$

Comment: $(12)^2=(1)(2)$.

Comment: A Hint: what's the fourth power of a permutation of signature $81^1$?

Comment: $81^1$? This is a big number, why you use that?

Comment: Bad idea, I meant $12^1$.

Comment: Note that $\pi^6=1$ so that $\delta^{24}=1$. This restricts the possible cycle types which can be part of $\delta$. What happens when you take the fourth power of each of these cycle types?

Comment: cycle of length $3$ will be $id$. Cycle of length $2$ will be in parts $(a)(b)$

Comment: So I have $\binom{23}{8}\binom{15}{3}\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3} \cdot (3-1)!^5 \cdot (1-1)!^4 $?

Comment: @Tester1998 And cycles of length $4,6,8,12,24$? (Anything which has order a factor of $24$) Once you know what happens to the cycle types, you can see what combination(s) might work for $\delta^4=\pi$

Comment: Oh god, it is a lot of checking like for $1$ of many exercises on exam.  I have doubts what is formal reason that you have choosen $24$ and check each factor of that

Comment: @Tester1998 If you understood what happened to cycles when you raised them to powers it would be quite easy.